# JQuery Pop up message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a custom pop up message, that appears, displays to the user for 5 seconds and then fades out. This works fine BUT if the use triggers the event multiple times and the time out is already running the message quickly disappears.

My function so far...

```
function showMessage(message) {
    $(".messageText").text(message);

    $(".message").fadeIn("slow");    

    closeBox = function(){
        $(".message").fadeOut("slow");    
    }

    clearInterval(closeBox);
    setInterval(closeBox, 5000);
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: can you include the code where you are calling showMessage from?

Comment: You can add a variable to save the state of the message box. If the box is showing, do not execute the function.

Comment: how about specifying timeout in fadeout function itself ?? will it work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var interval;

function showMessage(message) {
    $(".messageText").text(message);

    $(".message").fadeIn("slow");
    if(interval){ // If a interval is set.
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(closeBox, 5000);
}

function closeBox(){
    $(".message").fadeOut("slow");    
}
```

You need to assign the return of `setInterval` to a variable. This handle can be used to end the interval with `clearinterval`. (You can't clear a interval by function, only by interval handle)

Also, I pulled the `closeBox` function out of the `showMessage` function, it's not necessary to declare it every time `showMessage` is called.

Comment: and inverval should be interval..:)

Comment: jQuery's delay() was intended for scenarios like very this one.

Comment: @semir.babajic: that may be so, but I prefer telling a user how to fix his native JS, compared to telling him to be lazy.
Programmers shouldn't always be lazy, you learn more from re-inventing the wheel every now and then. (Especially on small things like this)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Agree. But I've already passed the school, now I'm more focused on saving my time as I'm completely business oriented developer. Saving development time and learning how things work under the hood sometimes come in clash. Both, time and knowledge are valuable, but time is precious.

Comment: @semir.babajic: You're not the person asking the question.

Comment: lol, you had me looking at the code for several minutes as I couldn't notice that `interval` was mistyped to `inverval` http://jsfiddle.net/cauFU/ than saw @bipen 's comment ... +1 anyways for not lazing out :)

Answer (score 4):

What about using jQuery delay?

Sample:

```
$("#container").fadeIn().delay(amoutOfTimeInMiliseconds).fadeOut();
```

Your function:

```
function showMessage(message) {
    $(".messageText").text(message);

    $(".message").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");    
}
```

It should work... Regards.